# if statement always true even with right inputs?

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm doing some checks for the month input in my project.
I scanf 2 characters. Let's say I successfully have taken "10" as input.
Then through an if statement I ask the compiler if the input taken is greater than 12 or lower than 01 , but in whatever occasion, the if statement is always true.

```
#define MAX_DAY 2
#define MAX_MONTH 2
#define MAX_YEAR 4

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    char day[MAX_DAY];
    char month[MAX_MONTH];
    char year[MAX_YEAR];
} date; //struct data

typedef struct {
    date date_of_flight;
} flight; //struct volo

int CheckMonth (flight list1);

int main() {

    flight list;

    int correct = 0;

    while (correct != 1) {
    printf("Month of departure: ");
    scanf("%2s", list.date_of_flight.month);
    correct = CheckMonth(list);
    }

    return 0;
}

int CheckMonth (flight list1) {

    int correct = 0;

    if ((list1.date_of_flight.month > 12) || (list1.date_of_flight.month < 01))  {
        printf("Wrong input. The right input should be between 01 (January) and 12 (December).\n");
    }
    else
    {
        correct = 1;
    }
    return correct;
}
```

If you're asking yourself why did I use **char month[]** instead of a simple int, it's because if I scanf "05" through an int, the scanf will only read 5.

Comment: For one thing your strings are too short for the NUL string terminator, and for another you are comparing a string *pointer* with a number. Please check compiler warnings.

Comment: I just figured it out by using `int val = atoi(list1.date_of_flight.month);` right before the if statement in `CheckMonth`.
And also comparing `(val > 12) || (val < 01)` of course. Thank you anyways.

Comment: The strings are still too short. Put `char month[MAX_MONTH+1];` etc. One reason it *appears* to work is that the variable is global, was initialised to all-0, and you have not entered data into the other strings.

Comment: Gotchu. Now I understood. :)
So I should put `[MAX_MONTH+1]` and such because the last one should be `'\0'`?

Comment: @SlimShadys Yes.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%2s", list.date_of_flight.month);`  Since the '%s' always appends a NUL byte to the input, using a MAX CHARACTER modifier, means the field `date_of_flight.month` must be 3 characters long. BUT it is only defined as 2 characters long, so the next field is corrupted

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%2s", list.date_of_flight.month);` this allows for 2 characters to be input by the user.  You state that the user entered "10"  Which is 0x3130.  Which will never be less than 12  suggest `int month = atoi( list.date_of_flight.month );`  Then check the variable `month` against 1 and 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare strings in your function.

```
if ((list1.date_of_flight.month > 12) || (list1.date_of_flight.month < 01))  {
    printf("Wrong input. The right input should be between 01 (January) and 12 (December).\n");
```

should actually be:

```
if ((strcmp(list1.date_of_flight.month, "12") > 0 ) || (strcmp(list1.date_of_flight.month, "01") < 0))  {
    printf("Wrong input. The right input should be between 01 (January) and 12 (December).\n");
}
```

`strcmp()` is a function in `<string.h>`. It returns 0 if the two strings are equal.

It returns a negative number if the first different character in the first string comes after that in the second string, based on ASCII value.

Otherwise, it returns a positive number.

Comment: This works as well. I put another solution in the comments down my question.
Thank you.